# How do I choose to create subnet or use customer provided in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What do I want to do: In a cloudformation template, if a user provides a list of subnet-ids, use them. Otherwise, create VPCs, subnets, etc.

The cloudformation parameter that I have defined to capture the user input is:

```
  useSubnet:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

And the condition I have set is:

```
  CreateVPC: !Equals [!Select [0, !Ref useSubnet], ""]
```

But, if the user does not select any subnet value in the list, the template fails with:

> Parameter validation failed: parameter value for parameter name
>   useSubnet does not exist.

I even tried using a different parameter to capture the user choice but still get the same error. That is:

```
  createVPC:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: true
  useSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
```

Condition is:

```
CreateVPC: !Equals [!Ref createVPC, true]
```

and using it as:

```
!If [CreateVPC, !Ref privateSubnet, !Ref useSubnet]
```

I get the same error...

Comment: I recommend that you provide two CloudFormation templates and have the user pick whichever fits his network design. One template builds the VPC, subnets etc. The other requires the user to supply his own VPC, subnet IDs etc.

Comment: Maybe you need to set a default (`''`) value for `useSubnet`?